# Anyone can request any of two accounts to be merged?

Tags: bug, merge-accounts

please try with two different user profile link and then proceed
https://stackoverflow.com/contact
option to be selected - **I need to merge user profiles**

I copied the contact form HTML block and changed some values like user email, user profile link, fkey.

And then I did run the HTML page from an incognito Chrome window (where no account signed in). And start to submit the form with

> I need to merge user profiles

And proceeded, It give success message with, confirmation email will be sent to both email id.

But the fact is, the user Profile links entered are not mine, also email id given was not a valid one. And no account was signed in during the submission of process. How it can be validated?

Or any-one can send to merge account to any of two different accounts?

The code I copied and successfully taken by Stack Overflow.

```
<form class="grid fd-column gs16 gsy" id="send-email" method="POST" action="https://stackoverflow.com/contact/submit">
                <div class="grid fd-column gs4 gsy">
                    <label class="grid--cell s-label" for="topic">What can we help you with?</label>
                    <div class="grid--cell s-select">
                        <select name="topic" id="topic">
                            <option value="">Please select a topic</option>
                                <option value="1">I lost my password</option>
                                <option value="2">I need to add or remove login credentials</option>
                                <option value="3">I need to delete my user profile</option>
                                <option value="4">I need to merge user profiles</option>
                                <option value="5">My question or answer was denied</option>
                                <option value="6">My question or answer did not meet quality standards</option>
                                <option value="7">My question was closed or put on hold</option>
                                <option value="8">I would like to advertise on Stack Exchange</option>
                                <option value="10">Stack Exchange content is being reproduced without attribution</option>
                                <option value="11">I need help with Stack Overflow Jobs</option>
                                <option value="9">Other</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p class="grid fd-column gs4 gsy">
                    <label class="grid--cell s-label" for="email">Your email</label>
                    <input class="grid--cell s-input" type="text" id="email" name="email" value="even@this.one" placeholder="your email">
                </p>
                <p class="grid fd-column gs4 gsy" id="profileUrlBlock" style="display: block;">
                    <label class="grid--cell s-label" for="profileUrl">Your profile link</label>
                    <input class="grid--cell s-input" type="text" id="profileLink" name="profileUrl" value="anyProfileLinkHere1" placeholder="paste your profile url here">
                </p>
                <p class="grid fd-column gs4 gsy" id="otherProfileUrlBlock" style="display: block;">
                    <label class="grid--cell s-label" for="otherProfileUrl">Your other profile link</label>
                    <input class="grid--cell s-input" type="text" id="otherProfileLink" name="otherProfileUrl" placeholder="paste the other profile url here" value="anyProfileLinkHere1">
                </p>
                <p class="grid fd-column gs4 gsy" id="scraperReportExternalContentUrlBlock" style="display: none;">
                    <label class="grid--cell s-label" for="scraperReportExternalContentUrl">Link to the site reproducing Stack Exchange content</label>
                    <input class="grid--cell s-input" type="text" id="scraperReportExternalContentUrl" name="scraperReportExternalContentUrl" placeholder="paste the url of the site that is reproducing our content here">
                </p>
                <p class="grid fd-column gs4 gsy" id="scraperReportInternalContentUrlBlock" style="display: none;">
                    <label class="grid--cell s-label" for="scraperReportInternalContentUrl">Link to the corresponding content on our site</label>
                    <input class="grid--cell s-input" type="text" id="scraperReportInternalContentUrl" name="scraperReportInternalContentUrl" placeholder="paste the url of the corresponding content on our site here">
                </p>
                <p class="grid fd-column gs4 gsy" id="scraperReportSearchTermsBlock" style="display: none;">
                    <label class="grid--cell s-label" for="scraperReportSearchTerms">Search terms</label>
                    <input class="grid--cell s-input" type="text" id="scraperReportSearchTerms" name="scraperReportSearchTerms" placeholder="paste the search terms that lead you to the other site here">
                </p>
                <p class="grid fd-column gs4 gsy" id="profileCVUrlBlock" style="display: none;">
                    <label class="grid--cell s-label" for="profileCVLink">Your Careers CV link</label>
                    <input class="grid--cell s-input" type="text" id="profileCVLink" name="profileCVLink" placeholder="paste your Careers CV profile url here, if any">
                </p>

                <p class="grid fd-column gs4 gsy">
                    <label class="grid--cell s-label" for="details"><span id="detail-prompt">Please describe your problem</span> <span class="detail-optional" style="display:none">(optional)</span></label>
                    <textarea class="grid--cell s-input" name="details" id="details"></textarea><br>
                    <span class="text-counter needs-detail mt4"></span>
                </p>
                <input type="hidden" name="fkey" value="giveAnyFakeKeyThatYouCanGetContactPage">
                <input type="hidden" name="referrer" value="https://stackoverflow.com/">
                <p>
                    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" "=""><br>
                    <span class="form-error" style="display: none;">all fields are required</span>
                </p>
            </form>
```

Comment: From [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts): "After you contact us, the Stack Exchange Team will reach out to verify that you own both accounts. If we can confirm your ownership, [...]"  --- Are you sure that you actually get the accounts merged, or just be able to send a contact form? (in the latter case, no harm is done except that the SE devs may get annoyed)

Comment: I can confirm that all my attempts to merge my account with Jon Skeet's account have failed so far.

Comment: The confirmation email would probably need to be...confirmed by the user. Since email is not valid, it will hardly complete

Comment: please try with two different profile id. and another thing is, if we given with [https://stackoverflow.com/users/anyNumberHere], it will give complete link with user name after loading, so we can easily get two valid user profile link

Comment: @yivi that might not go as you might have planned. Jon Skeet may end up becoming yivi if successful

Comment: yes, It will send confirmation mail to the both user profile, where the data / merge request given by non-user of SO , even guest of SO      simple thing, any one can give a merge request to any of two accounts, it's not about merging, but about request, fake request...

Comment: Regardless, this is not how you you do Responsible Disclosure.https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322634/does-so-have-a-bug-bounty

Comment: just try with the above html just by '/user/1' and '/user/2' profiles. with invalid email and a fkey

Comment: @SathiyaSeelanD the step 2 in the process is to respond to the confirmation email. How would that be possible with a fake request unless you gain access to others' email account?

Comment: Let me point you to https://stackexchange.com/about/security and follow the advice given there.

Comment: @SurajRao I can understand the process of merging suraj, I have simple question, can any user request to any of two accounts. where he/she is not owner of any account given. so the request is fake one right. then why it's open and to  all, and how SO validating the user given the request

Comment: *"where he/she is not owner of any account given"* – You can't really be signed in as two users at once, so at least one of the two accounts you're about to merge will by definition "not be owned by you", where "you" is "the currently signed in user". That's why there's a separate email confirmation step to confirm ownership.

Comment: @deceze _"the currently signed in user"_ great deceze, I clearly mentioned it no account was signed in during the process. So non-user of SO even can submit a merge request for two account url(which can be easily get from SO)

Comment: Again, *at least one* account will always not be signed in. You could argue that at least one of the to-be-merged accounts should maybe be signed in/submit the request, but since this won't cover *both* accounts either way it will require an email confirmation step, so it doesn't *really* matter.

Comment: @deceze still can't agree, please use the html code given and change anyProfileLinkHere1 ,anyProfileLinkHere2 and giveAnyFakeKeyThatYouCanGetContactPage values. and proceed.

Comment: You can submit it yes... but unless you answer the confirmation at the other end - nothing's going to happen... what's the problem?

Comment: @SathiyaSeelanD so what is your step 2? after submit what do you do?

Comment: @JonClements yes nothing will happen. but why the option is open when no user signed in.

Comment: My guess would be *because it doesn't really matter*, and/or there's some usability case the devs have identified where you *can't* be required to be signed in as one of the accounts yet must still be able to use the feature.

Comment: @SurajRao they are allowing to request where no account is signed in. it should not be there where no user logged in, untill one of the account url should to be the signed-in user's

Comment: @SathiyaSeelanD but do you understand it is still impossible to merge an account that's not yours, since all requests are manually confirmed?

Comment: yes @yivi i completely understand. Think in this way, when you are logged out you can request for any two different accounts. It' will be confirmed but why the feature enabled for non-user of SO

Comment: Only a dev can tell for which workflow it is needed...

Comment: You keep asking 'why is it enabled'..... Why not? As deceze was saying: since you require email validation regardless.... Why does it matter?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not possible for someone to merge accounts that they do *not* own. We have to open the form to users that aren't able to authenticate since a major use case is ***because they can't authenticate to one or both of the accounts*** and need our help getting back into them. Sometimes, they don't know what option to select.

Merges are manually verified by staff - we're not going to merge accounts until we can be certain that you own them. In fact, we've often had to just say *sorry, we can't do this merge, it's regrettable that you can't access that account any longer because it has a bit of rep, but we can't be sure that you own it.*

Now you *can* do it mostly automatically if you can authenticate with both accounts, but you'll *still* end up in a merge queue that someone with developer access needs to give a final check and okay to prior to the merge going through.

That we're *extremely* paranoid about inadvertently exposing PII is the whole reason why merging was made an employee-only feature, even moderators can't merge accounts, even if they're sure it's the same person - they can only contact us to verify it and do it for them.

To reiterate: The process is ***manual inspection*** of information, which is what enables us to present the form for a lot of use cases, many of which are surrounding users that can't log in.